# Bootstrap - Scaling Images in a Specific Way

Tags: javascript, css

I have tried searching as much as I can through google as well as figuring out the issue myself, but no matter what I try(albeit my knowledge is very limited) I cannot figure out how to scale my image with bootstrap.

Basically I have two flex boxes next to each other, one I want to display the image and the other displays a checklist of items. Each column takes up 6 spots so they are even. The issue is I cannot seem to scale my image down, it is a zoomed in version of my background image that I have added.

This is my code:

```
<!--about section-->
<section id="about" class="bg-info">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <!--about img col-->
      <div class="col-md-6 about-picture height-80"></div>
      <!--about text col-->
      <div class="col-md-6 about-text height-80 px-5 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

This is what I am using in my css file for the image itself

```
.about-picture{
    background: url(../VScode/images/background.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` will "resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges".

You might want to choose a different `background-size` (and `background-repeat`). See: [MDN: background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I tried it that way before but it doesn't work the way I want it to work. When changing it to contain, the image itself doesn't stretch across the entire flex box so there are so the background color is showing

Comment: I'm not sure what the result are supposed to look... To stretch the image, try `background-size: 100% 100%;`, to tile the image, try `background-size: contain; background-repeat: repeat;` (`repeat-x` and `repeat-y` is also available)

Comment: Thank you again for the reply! I will add some images if you are curious because they may be able to explain what I mean in a better way. Don't feel any pressure to look, I am unsure if I can add images to comments so I just created an imgur link. https://imgur.com/a/0Rjh2Du if you do happen to see, the bottom image is what I want but without it being zoomed in, the top image is what I tried in your first post(or example 1 vs example 2). And strangely enough in your second post none of those things actually change the image itself

Comment: You are welcome :) In this example, I think `background-size: cover;` might be the better choice. Stretch the image to fill the box might make the picture look strange (keep in mind user will view the page with different window size)... https://jsfiddle.net/0x6e73m5/2/